# How to use emacsclient to ask for a password

Tags: emacsclient, passwords

When I run `vs-push` (<kbd>C-x v P</kbd>) the program `ssh-askpass` gets execute to ask for the password of the SSH key. There are several different implementations. I am wondering if I can use `emacsclient` to redirect the question back to the Emacs frame, which initiated the Git push. Is this possible?